# Get week LINQ to SQL for google charts

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Im having an issue i cant get past, here's my controller for reporting -

```
    var week = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);                   

    List<LeaveChartVM> data = new List<LeaveChartVM>();
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {        
        data = ( from u in db.UserProfiles
                select new LeaveChartVM
                {
                Users = (from up in db.UserProfiles
                         select up).Count(),

                OnLeaveToday = (from tol in db.CalendarData
                                where (today >= tol.StartTime && today <= tol.EndTime)
                                select tol).Count(),                                    

                SickLeave = (from sl in db.CalendarData
                             where sl.LeaveType == "5"
                             select sl).Count(),

                AnnualLeave = (from al in db.CalendarData
                               where al.LeaveType == "1"
                               select al).Count()
            }).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

Could some one help me return data for this week only please? Ive managed to return todays sickness and leave but i want to create a line chart that returns data for the week.

Adding to this as info wasnt great, heres the table structures for calendarDatas -

```
[Subject]
  ,[Description]
  ,[StartTime]
  ,[EndTime]
  ,[AllDay]
  ,[Recurrence]
  ,[RecurrenceRule]
  ,[LeaveType]
  ,[StartTimeZone]
  ,[EndTimeZone]
  ,[UserId]
  ,[EventStatus]
  ,[ApporovedId]
  ,[ApprovedDate]
  ,[Duration]
  ,[EventAction]
  ,[EventDate]
  ,[uid]
  ,[colourId]
  ,[UserProfiles_Id]
```

and then also for UserProfiles -

```
[Forenames]
  ,[Surnames]
  ,[Fullname]
  ,[EmployementType]
  ,[Displayname]
  ,[TeamId]
  ,[ShiftPatternId]
  ,[DepartmentId]
  ,[DateJoined]
  ,[DivsionId]
  ,[WindowsUser]
  ,[DateCreated]
  ,[DateOfAction]
  ,[ActionId]
  ,[Division_Id]
```

What i am wanting to return is people both on Annual Leave and sick leave over the past 7 working days and also the current day.

Comment: Please post the *relevant* code only and the structure of CalendarData. It's impossible to answer how to get a certain week's data when we don't even know if you *have* a DateTime column

Comment: I don't think that it's built in.

You can make a if statement.

if sonday... get the 6 days after...

if monday... get the day before and the 5 days after...

......

Comment: @SimonR - Your code is confusing. You are selecting for each user different things without "binding" it to the specific user. + the question itself about 1 day vs. a week. Please say what is your desired output for data and also how does the different tables look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime oneWeekAgo = today.AddDays(-7);

// usage
OnLeaveThisWeek = 
    (from tol in db.CalendarData
     where (tol.StartTime >= oneWeekAgo && tol.EndTime <= today)
     select tol).Count()
```

Make sure your `today` and `oneWeekAgo` values match the logic you need, i.e. whether it is today inclusive or not, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this got me what i wanted.